# Multiple file upload scripts have stopped working

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a site with multiple file uploaders on it, all of which have stopped working.

I am getting no errors; it's like the PHP just refuses to acknowledge the $_FILES handler.
This only occurs on the live server; on my local development system the exact same files work fine.

The HTML I use is:

```
<input type="file" name="docfile">
```

The PHP is:

```
if ($_FILES['docfile']['name'] != '') {
        if (!file_exists('upld/documents/'.$docid)) {
            mkdir('upld/documents/'.$docid, 0777, true);
        }

        //sanitise filename
        $cleanname = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $_FILES['docfile']['name']);
        $upfile =  "v0-" . $cleanname;

        //Upload image
        $temp = $_FILES['docfile']['tmp_name'];
        $dest = "upld/documents/".$docid."/";

        if(move_uploaded_file($temp,$dest.$upfile))
        {
            //save file name in DB MySQL stuff here
        } else {
            $errors[] = "There was an error while uploading file";
        }
    }
```

Could a change on the server have affected this?

Comment: I would like to know if you have defined `enctype= multipart/form-data` in `<form>` tag. also check what is your post_max_size in php.ini.

Comment: Sure it could, e.g. if php.ini has changed http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.file-uploads

Comment: @AlexBlex it was the php.ini after all, someone had run an update and reset the file_uploads to OFF. Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it and give you points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that someone had run an update on the server which had reset the php.ini setting `file_uploads` to OFF.

Once I changed it back to ON everything worked again.